# msolul80.Dll failed to regesiter

Tags: c#, .net

when install application in the customer erorr ocured
msolul80.Dll failed to regesiter countact your support personal what this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you must install Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

1. Search for this dll, if you won't find him then search it over the develpoer machine where the application works.
2. See that you have all of this dll depends - http://www.dependencywalker.com/
3. Register msolul80.dll on cmd with: regsvr32 msolul80.dll